# Flushing just the homepage cache in Varnish

Tags: magento-1.7, nginx, varnish, turpentine

I currently run nginx with Varnish in front on my Magento instance. I use Turpentine as the Varnish module for Magento. Without clearing the entire Varnish cache, is it possible just to flush the homepage cache?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to clear varnish and not about magento

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt for me this is a valid question as the Turpentine extension is sending the flush commands to Varnish.

Comment: ask the support contact of the module for this feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not through Turpentine, but you can run this command (as root/sudo) to flush just the homepage (may need to adjust if Magento is not installed at the top level of your site):

```
varnishadm ban.url '^/(?:index\.php/?)?$'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no page in the module by default.
Though, you could create your own page in the admin with a form to submit an URL.

Within the controller you only need a few lines of code to actually ban a URL from the Varnish cache.

```
$sockets = Mage::helper( 'turpentine/varnish' )->getSockets();
foreach($sockets  as $socket) {
   $socket->ban( 'req.http.host', '==', '{host_name}', '&&', 'req.url', '==', '{path}');
}
```